# CouchDB: bulk_docs returning incorrect status code

Tags: couchdb, pouchdb, couchdb-futon

I'm working on syncing a PouchDB database (with Angular) with a CouchDB database.

When the replication is in progress, the code is issuing a POST request to do a bulk update to `http://127.0.0.1:5984/testdb/_bulk_docs`.

I have a validation rule on database to reject unauthorized writes, and it generates a forbidden error. Therefore, the server is responding with a JSON response as `[{"id":"0951db944e729c981ad3964c22002d55","rev":"8-ccdcb52743cae43c5870113f09f2e25a","error":"forbidden","reason":"Not Authorized"}]`

According [to the docs (at the end of the page)](http://docs.couchdb.org/en/1.6.1/api/database/bulk-api.html#db-bulk-docs), the above response should generate a `417 Expectation Failed` status code. However, it currently generates a `201 Created` status code.

Because of the incorrect response code, the client (PouchDB) shows as all records synced, but the updates are not written to the server (CouchDB).

Is there a config option to change this status code?

Fore reference, my `validate_doc_update` function is as following.

```
function(newDoc, oldDoc, userCtx){ 
    if (!userCtx) throw({forbidden: 'Need a user to update'});

    if((userCtx.roles.indexOf('_admin') == -1) && (userCtx.roles.indexOf('backend:manager') == -1)){
           throw({forbidden: "Not Authorized"});
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `417:expectation failed` status code only works when the `all_or_nothing` parameter is set to true. By default this parameter is false.

The default bulk update transaction mode in couchdb is [non atomic](http://docs.couchdb.org/en/1.6.1/api/database/bulk-api.html#bulk-documents-transaction-semantics) which guarantees that only some of the documents will be saved. If the document is not saved the api returns an error object like you got along with a list of documents that were in fact successfully saved. So `201` seems to be the correct response.

Then you've got to walk through the response to find which documents failed and manually update them.

In case of `all_or_nothing` mode however a  success will be returned only if all the documents have been updated.

While syncing you can also use the [_replicate](http://docs.couchdb.org/en/1.6.1/api/server/common.html#replicate) endpoint that has many other features that bulk update does not have.

Comment: Seems you're right. I thought it would give a 417 error if at least 1 record failed to sync. Looks like I'll have to handle the auth errors manually.